# how can i retrieve the data from local storage in html page using controller and service?

Tags: angularjs

my code to store the data is:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope','$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.auth = function () {

        if ($scope.txtName.toLowerCase() == 'admin'
            && $scope.txtPass.toLowerCase() == 'password') {
            $location.path('/addcustomerpage');
        } else {
            $scope.error = true;
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('addcustomer', ['$scope','$location','contactService',
    function ($scope, $location, contactService) {
        $scope.contactObj={
            name: "",
            phoneNumber:"",
            email:""
        };

        $scope.addContact = function (contactObj) {
            $scope.contactObj.name=contactObj.name;
            $scope.contactObj.phoneNumber=contactObj.phoneNumber;
            $scope.contactObj.email=contactObj.email;
            contactService.saveContact($scope.contactObj);
            $location.path('/detail');
        }

}]);
```

This is my service:

```
var services = angular.module('msales.services', []);

// Services for singletons, and Factories for more complex
// functions such as Object Literals and more complicated use cases.

services.service('contactService', function () {
    var contactArray=[];

    this.saveContact=function(contactObject){

    // Parse the serialized data back into an array of objects
    contactArray = localStorage.getItem("ContactList");

    // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else)
    // onto the array
    if(contactArray == null || contactArray == ""){
        contactArray=[];
        contactArray.push(contactObject);
    } else {
        contactArray=JSON.parse(contactArray);

        contactArray.push(contactObject);
    }

    // Re-serialize the array back into a string and store it in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("ContactList", JSON.stringify(contactArray));
}
```

Comment: Don't put the question in the title. Your code seems fine - what problem are you facing with the `localStorage` code?

Comment: i am just not able to fetch the data from local storage how can i do it..?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("ContactList");` - Doesn't this fetch the local storage data?